# Authorizing into the BEAP (Bloomberg Enterprise Access Point) from Excel VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, rest, bloomberg

I am looking for the possibility to establish direct REST API call from Excel to Bloomberg Data License endpoints. Does anyone has the experience?

I´ve got stuck on the stage of authorisation. In the Python sample code I see that it happens with the help of "bwslib" library. How exactly to authenticate requests from Excel VBA scripts?

Comment: Did you ask Bloomberg? Data license users have a dedicated support.

Comment: Yes, I asked. They answered that they haven't come across any clients who have integrated their RESTAPI in this manner. Also that the one part that might be an issue would be the creation of the JSON Web Token (JWT) as it is encoded using base64 which can be a little bit complicated to set up. The possible solution would be to use alternative middleware applications to connect to the RESTAPI.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am embarking on the same for a client and would be happy to collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use bwslib to generate JWT token. This library contains only helper classes for convenience. JWT is an open standard and you can write your own code to generate it. You can also review the source code in bswlib and see how the token is generated, then do the same in your own programming language. jwt.io provides code examples in many programming languages.

In summary, DL REST API does not 'require' bwslib or any other Bloomberg library.